# DBMS OUTPUT PUT doesn't print anything

Tags: oracle, plsql, dbms-output

I'm new to PL/SQL and I want to show the following message.
When I compile it in SQL Developer I only get

```
  PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

My code is this:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
  mesaj VARCHAR2 (100) := 'PL/SQL';
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(mesaj);
END;
/
```

Comment: Does it work if you use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` instead?

Comment: @HellmarBecker yes it does!

Comment: Then it is probably just line buffering - if the line is not finished nothing is printed.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add an end-of-line marker by calling `DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE;`. End-of-line marker is added by `PUT_LINE` but not by `PUT`.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
  mesaj VARCHAR2 (100) := 'PL/SQL';
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(mesaj);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

> The PUT procedure and PUT_LINE procedure in this package enable you to
>   place information in a buffer that can be read by another procedure or
>   package.
>
> When you call `PUT_LINE`, the item you specify is automatically followed
>   by an end-of-line marker.

If you make calls to `PUT` to build a line, you must add your own end-of-line marker by calling NEW_LINE, or you can try `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` which appends each line with an end-of-line marker.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
  mesaj VARCHAR2 (100) := 'PL/SQL';
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(mesaj);
END;
/
```

**PUT** - This procedure places a partial line in the buffer.
 **PUT_LINE** - This procedure places a line in the buffer.

Comment: This is a 4+ year old question ... that you answered essentially with the same content as the 4 year old comment by  Hellmar Becker .... why?