# DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT is not printing data ,I've tried every solution that I found in the forum

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a weird problem concerning `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT` - it is not printing data. I've tried these solutions:

```
1 - SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
2 - Enable DBMS_OUTPUT
```

and nothing works.

Comment: what version of SQL Developer and what version of your database? Newer versions of sqldeveloper won't show dbms_output on a 10g instance due to a change in the jdbc driver

Comment: please share the solutions you have found/tried, plus the actual code you are using for a test

Answer (score 1):

pick dbms_output from the view menu.
The window should pop open.

There is a plus sign on the window.
Pick that and signin to the schema you are running in.

```
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('hello world');
end;
```

When you run it, "hello world" should appear in the window.

Comment: actually my friends solve this with SET SERVEROUTPUT ON and i dont khow why its didn't work for me or any solution that i tried, should i download another sql dev version ?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36298377/dbms-output-put-is-not-printing-data/36298428) link and see if it is useful.

Could not add it as a comment due to reputation restriction.

**Edited part starts here:**

I executed the following in Oracle LiveSQL and here is how it works.

```
exec dbms_output.put_line('A' || CHR(10) || 'B');     --prints

begin
    dbms_output.put('A');
    dbms_output.put('B');
   -- dbms_output.put_line(' ');   --doesn't print
end;    

begin
    dbms_output.put('A');
    dbms_output.put('B');
    dbms_output.put_line(' ');  --prints
end;

begin
    dbms_output.put('A');
    dbms_output.put('B');
    dbms_output.new_line;       --prints
end;

begin
    dbms_output.put('A');
    dbms_output.put('B');
    dbms_output.put('');       --doesn't print
end;
```

Comment: I've seen this nothing work for me i know that's weird

Comment: Which version of SQL Developer are you using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34737094/5199194
Check here and let me know if even this doesn't work

Comment: i have oracle 10g